# In mongodb,How to use ruby on rails "migration" tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

In ruby on rails normally use SQLite as a database.so a special property of rails called migration are work.but when we use "mongodb" as a database in rails.I see there have no migrate folder in the db directory.
Is there any way to use this migration property in rails when use mongodb.

Comment: AFAIK you need a separate gem, Googling for "rails mongodb migrations" might be a good place to start.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.1.0/mongoid-rails/#using-mongoid-with-a-new-rails-application), `db:migrate:` Exists only for dependency purposes, but does not actually do anything. 
However, because I am not sure of what version of rails you're using, how your project was setup and if you intend using just `mongodb` I will describe the process for both possibilities from scratch with all assumptions if any clearly stated.

This approach assumes you want to use `mongodb` alone

1. Create your Rails app with the `--skip-active-record` switch.
2. Remove `sqlite3` from your `Gemfile`
3. add `gem 'mongoid'` to your `Gemfile`
4. and run `bundle`
5. Run `rails g mongoid:config`
6. Check your `application.rb` file and make sure that inside the 'class Application' you have this line `Mongoid.load! './config/mongoid.yml'` It's sometimes not included when the config is generated, but is needed to use `Mongoid`.
7. `Mongoid` is ready to go.

The Rails generators for `model`, `scaffold`, etc have been overridden by `Mongoid`. Any models, scaffolds etc that you create will create classes that include the Mongoid::Document module instead of inheriting from ApplicationRecord in the models folder.

For instance, when you run

`rails g model person first_name last_name email_address`

if you open up the file `app/models/person.rb`

You'd see

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :email_address, type: String
end
```